# MS CRM2013 IFRAME display Error

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8, dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-2013

I am practicing with **Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013** using REST 0Data endpoint with Web Resources.I have added an Iframe in case form and assigned a pagein the IFRAME URL and  wrote the code snippet given on [Microsoft Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx)

[image: see the structure of my CRM Web Resouces with Code]

Now when I open a case from CRM Sales dashboard to check this IFRAME, it showing different errors in different browsers

**in Chrome** it display the text of the page but gives below error repeatedly

> Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at
>   "https://diecho.crm5.dynamics.com"  from accessing a frame at
>   "https://diecho.crm5.dynamics.com".   The frame being accessed is
>   sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.

**in Firefox** it display the text and when I open the Only Iframe code in different tab it gives below error in console

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   https://diecho.crm5.dynamics.com//ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"
>
> Error: Context is not available. { throw new Error("Context is not available."); }
>
> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/987fsdr3e47f993ofskljd9/zone1-1003.js

**in IE8** it gives below error:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame  To help protect the
>   security of information you enter into this website,  the publisher of
>   this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

[image: see IFRAME error in IE8 in CRM 2013]

Please Help me

- How to fix these errors?
- What am I missing to enable on CRM or on Browser side to see the page in IFRAME?

Comment: Your reference to `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` is wrong. You are not already in a directory, you are the top, because the HTM page is not under `sample_` so there is no need for `..\`. Is this running in an IFRAME or embedded as a WebResource?

Comment: yes. this is on an IFRAME

Comment: Thank you very much . Now getting only one Error: `TypeError: Xrm.Page.data is null`

Comment: That makes sense because an IFRAME doesn't have the form data. Can you show the code fragment that is throwing this error? It isn't in the example files from Microsoft you linked to in your question so I can't see where you are calling `Xrm.Page.data`.

Comment: Yes. that I Wrote to check some functionality on Iframe.

Comment: I want that when i click on detail button in the Case form. a new Iframe would be open  where i can access Xrm data and can work further. Hope you get my point

Comment: Then you need to pass the Object Id as part of the IFRAME URL. http://ayazahmad.wordpress.com/2007/02/23/how-to-pass-entity-guid-and-entity-type-to-custom-applications-hosted-in-iframe/

Answer (score 1):

In the Form Editor double click the iframe and make sure that the "Restrict cross-frame scripting, where supported." option is not checked.

Comment: Oh Thanks, Looking for other fixes too

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing OData from HTML page, `Xrm.Page.Context` will throw you an error. In place of that you should use `parent.Xrm.Page.Context`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the same code as MSDN and it worked successfully.

```
<html><head>
<title>JQuery REST Data Operations</title>    
<script src="../gap_jscript/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../gap_jscript/SDK.JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../gap_jscript/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../gap_jscript/TestODATAExample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Segoe UI; background-color: white;">
<button title="Click this button to start the sample." id="start">Start</button>
<button title="Click this button to reset the sample." disabled="disabled" id="reset">Reset</button>
<ol id="output">
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: :-) Good point. Are you using CRM online. Please try this link. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2643142. In your case enter *.dynamics.com Did you tried the fiddler results?

Comment: this time i check few new error in Console of IE9 :
`SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_disabled'`

Comment: and other is `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'apply': object is null or undefined`

Comment: That code works perfectly but Now i want to change the code . i will surely paste my snippet very soon

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Looks like  your web resource files relative path is wrong. Make sure its new_ or sample_ for jquery1.9.1.min.js

Try the below code<script src="../new_jquery1.9.1.min.js"type="text/javascript</script>
<script src="../sample_Scripts/SDK.JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../sample_Scripts/JQueryRESTDataOperationsSample.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="../sample_Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>

Comment: Thank you very much.. Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks